# Sort a list of JodaTime dates by collections.sort

Tags: android, sorting, jodatime

I am using this algorithm to sort the list of dates in ascending order:

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
            DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(e1.getStartDate());
            DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(e2.getStartDate());
            return dt1.isBefore(dt2)? 1:0;
        }
    });
    Event first = eventList.get(0);
```

My question is, is this the best and correct way of doing things ?

This is the second suggestion:

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
            DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(e1.getStartDate());
            DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(e2.getStartDate());
            if(dt1.isBefore(dt2))
                return -1;
            else if(dt1.isAfter(dt2))
                return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    });
    Event first = eventList.get(0);
```

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T), `compare` should return "a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second." So your return statement doesn't seem correct as it doesn't account for `dt2` happening before `dt1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 alternatives.

**1-** use a `Comparator` that compares the `DateTime` for each `Event`:

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Event event1, Event event2) {
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(event1.getStartDate());
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(event2.getStartDate());
        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
});
```

Actually, if `getStartDate()` returns a `java.util.Date`, you don't need to create a `DateTime` because `java.util.Date` also implements `Comparable`. In this case, you could just do:

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Event event1, Event event2) {
        return event1.getStartDate().compareTo(event2.getStartDate());
    }
});
```

**2-** make `Event` implements `Comparable`:

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event other) {
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(this.getStartDate());
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(other.getStartDate());
        return dt1.compareTo(dt2);
    }
}

Collections.sort(eventList);
```

In this case, `Collections.sort` will use `Event.compareTo` method to sort.

Again, if `getStartDate()` returns a `java.util.Date`, you just need to do:

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event other) {
        return this.getStartDate().compareTo(other.getStartDate());
    }
}
```

---

Which one to choose? It depends.

If you use alternative 2 (implementing `Comparable`), it means that comparing the start date is the "**natural order**" of `Event` objects (the "normal"/"usual" way of sorting events).

Using a `Comparator` (in my opinion) is an alternative when you want to use a different criteria (other than the "**natural order**") to sort.

But it's up to you to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Since `DateTime` already implements the `Comparable` interface, you could do:

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(e1.getStartDate());
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(e2.getStartDate());
        return dt1.compareTo(dt2);
    }
});
```